# Returning promise value in event callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using angular drag and drop module: https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

I'm interested in this event

> **dnd-drop** Optional expression that is invoked when an element is
>   dropped on the list.
>
> The return value determines the further handling of the drop:
>
> false The drop will be canceled and the element won't be inserted.
>
> true Signalises that the drop is allowed, but the dnd-drop callback
>   will take care of inserting the element.

Inside this event callback i make a request to my REST server to see if item can be dropped, and i want to return true or false based on its response. So the code looks something like this:

```
function dropCallback(){
    var value;
    $http.post('url', data)
        .then(function success(){
            value = true;
        }, function error(){
            value = false;
        });
    return value;
}
```

So return value is undefined, because callbacks will be executed after getting response from the server.
How should i refactor my code to achieve this goal?

Comment: You'll probably want to look at this project's issues related to this [#168](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/issues/168) and [#173](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/issues/173)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the event's documentation does not say anything about Promises being accepted as return values of the callback - the answer is: **you can't**.

The request you make will be added to the end of the execution stack (so it will be executed later, after all the current jobs are done). It won't interrupt the callback's execution. So the callback execution will just reach the code end, and your request response handler won't affect callback's returned value.